# Separate gradle project for JavaScript views

Tags: javascript, gradle

I'm using Spring-Boot and I want to have separate gradle project just for angularjs views.

webapp contains only `*.js` and `*.html` in `src/main/webapp`

After `gradle war` I have in `webapp.war` every js/html that I want but in `controller.war` I have only java classes, no js/html.

my uber build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project("controller") {
    apply plugin: "spring-boot"
    apply plugin: "war"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":persistence")
        compile project(":webapp")
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.1.RELEASE"
    }
}

project("persistence") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    dependencies {
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.0.1.RELEASE"
    }
}

project("webapp") {
    apply plugin: "war"
}
```

Why `compile project(":webapp")` doesn't include my js/html files and how can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but as far as I understood You want to include a `war` file into another one. This is not possible and will bring no effect. For grouping multiple projects `ear` archive should be used.

Comment: Where do you want the js/hmtl files to be in controller.war?

Comment: @PerrynFowler There, where they would be in project whose made from a combination of controller and webapp project into one. I guest then it would be just in the root of controller.

Comment: @Opal I don't want to include war. I want to include files from webapp into controller project and then package this into war.

Comment: @WojciechKo can You please set up a simple project on GitHub and let others try (with a description of what You'd like to be where)?

Comment: @Opal here you go: https://github.com/WojciechKo/spring-boot-fun I need to divide `webapp` project into java only project and js/html only project.

Comment: Ok. Basiacally I see 2 options. 1 is to configure a single project where all sources (java, web) will be under on folder hierarchy. 2 is to create it separately, and client part as well as server will be built to a `war` artifact. Both `war` files will be packed into `ear` that is going to be deployed on the application server. If the second option is what You're looking for will prepare it on tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that You project is configured perfectly fine! After executing: `./gradlew clean :webapp:build` under project dir and then: `java -jar webapp/build/libs/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ` everything works fine. Also project structure looks good. How can I help You?

Comment: @Opal I need to move every java files from `webapp` project into new project called `controller`.